# Set items in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, header

How can I make my

- myvecC set  as -9 in the array for 4 times.
- myvecD set "Mom" for the array 7 times.

Then be able to change a each item in the array. I don't know how to make it so that I can set my new items in the array

```
 int main()
{   
vector<int> myvecA;
vector<int> myvecB(10);
vector<int> myvecC(4,-9);
vector<string> myvecD(7, "MOM!");

cout << "Vector A size: " << myvecA.size() << endl;
cout << "Vector B size: " << myvecB.size() << endl;
cout << "Vector C size: " << myvecC.size() << endl;
cout << "Vector D size: " << myvecD.size() << endl;

cout << "Vector A capacity: " << myvecA.capacity() << endl;
cout << "Vector B capacity: " << myvecB.capacity() << endl;
cout << "Vector C capacity: " << myvecC.capacity() << endl;
cout << "Vector D capacity: " << myvecD.capacity() << endl;

cout << endl;
cout << "Vector B: " << endl;
myvecB[3] = 43;
myvecB[7] = 17;
for (int i = 0; i<myvecB.size(); i++)
    cout << myvecB[i] << endl;

cout << endl;
cout << "Vector C: " << endl;
myvecC[2] = 50;
for (int i = 0; i<myvecC.size(); i++)
    cout << myvecC[i] << endl;

cout << endl;
cout << "Vector D: " << endl;
myvecD[6] = "Shut up kids.";
for (int i = 0; i<myvecD.size(); i++)
    cout << myvecD[i] << endl;
```

template.h

```
 template <class V>
 class vector {
 public:
 vector() : sizearr(0) {}
 vector(int x) : sizearr(x) {}
 vector(int x, const V &v) : sizearr(x) {}

int size();
int capacity();
private:
int sizearr;
int sizecap;
};

template <class V>
 int vector<V>::size() {
 return sizearr;
}

template<class V>
 inline int vector<V>::capacity()
{
 sizecap = sizearr * 2;
 return sizecap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a parameter do that for you, but you will need an array in your private class variables perhaps Type list* or whatever you want to call it.
It seems that the first parameter from the vector class object dictates the size of the vector and the second one what needs to be inserted. 
My suggestion:

'a' is the capacity of the array,
'Type V' is what gets inserted in the list array,
0 and NULL are for objects that don't have any parameter

```
vector(int a = 0 ,Type V = NULL) //This constructor can serve as your default constructor too
{
  sizearr = a;
  sizecap = a;
  list = new Type[sizecap];

  for(int i=0;i<sizecap;i++)
  {
    list[i] = b;
    }
}
```